# Wordpress - Database

Tags: wordpress

New to Wordpress.

I am aware the default database to Wordpress is MySQL.

Like livejournal, i have a small requirement which allows Admin to post content and registered users on the website are allowed to post contents.

I decided to go with Wordpress, but still have not done much research on allowing registered users to post contents as like admin.

I am wondering, What database would be the best to go with ? 
SQL or MySQL ?

Also, whether these contents are stored in the Database or in the form of .doc ?

Answer (score 0):

The database you use doesn't matter as long as Wordpress supports it.

Comment functionality is built into Wordpress. You don't need to do any custom development to make it happen. If you only want registered users to be able to comment, you'll have to make a setting requiring users to be registered and logged in to comment. This setting is under Settings - Discussion. Comments are stored in the database.

Comment: Let me explain, An admin can post the blog. Any registered users can post the blog. Anyone ( Anonymous Users ) can post the comments.  My question is, where is this blogs are saved or stored ?

Answer (score 0):

Those are a few questions in one, so I'll answer each one of its own and paraphrase:

### *Can Wordpress use some other database than MySQL?*

No, Wordpress only supports MySQL, so there is no choice.

### *Are the posts or pages/content in Wordpress stored in a database or in a .doc file*

The contents of posts in Wordpress, just like in liveJournal, are actually stored in a database.

### *Is it possible to allow users in Wordpress to submit content that an admin can then review and publish/delete later etc.*

**Yes.** Very much so. I believe it's built into Wordpress, you just need to have a registered user and enable the feature.

Comment: Is it possible to allow users in Wordpress to submit content than an admin can then review and publish/delete later etc.                                                                 So, any registered users on my blogging website can post content. We need to create a Registeration Page for users to register.

Comment: I think they have to be editors, authors or contributers - not any registered user. You can change the default roles of new users, but that's generally how it works.

Comment: What i heard was, Wordpress can have SQL 2008 Version database also ..?

Comment: And also, How will i handle the User Registration ? Does Wordpress or Wordpress Plugins Supports User Registration ? Roles & Responsbilities - Like Authors, Editors, Contributors - I can understand it.

Comment: Nope. You can install a special version called wordpress sql install: http://wordpress.visitmix.com/download but that's a beta and I bet most plugins will be incompatible. I have to ask you, why do you want to install on ms sql server in the first place?

Comment: Wordpress hasndles users, registration and all that by itself. It uses it's own users/authentication, so those users are only defined and used within the wordpress database, not the sql server users windows users or anything like that.

Comment: reason, why i want to go for SQL - is that it has reporting services and other additional features. Me, myself a SQL Expert as compared to MySQL. So, i  thought if we use SQL - it would be easy to handle.

Comment: And in the terms of User Registration,  As per my understanding from your comment - Wordpress handles all user registration. But we need a defined page for User Registration ? Does wordpress provides any page for that ?

Comment: Wordpress provides anything you need. If it doesn't have something you need by default it has a built in plugin library where you can find almost anything. The wordpress developer community is so big that you can find anything you ever wanted to do (almost)